# Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$\begin{bmatrix}-k_1-k_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 k_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -k_2 & 0 & -k_3 & k_4 \\
 0 & 0 & k_3 & -k_4\end{bmatrix}$$

How can I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the $4 \times 4$ matrix that consists of symbols?

I have tried a lot but it makes no sense.

Comment: Does anything prevent you to do the same as for a matrix with numbers? There's no difference in the procedure. If you don't see any special patterns, just find the characteristic polynomial and proceed as usual.

Comment: Hmm. Okay i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it consists only of symbols, but you can compute its eigenvalues as always: computing the roots of the characteristic polynomial, which is $$x^4+(k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4)x^3+(k_1k_3+k_1k_4+k_2k_3+k_2k_4)x^2.$$The eigenvalues are $0$ (twice), $-k_1-k_2$, and $-k_3-k_4$. Now, you can compute the eigenvectors by the usual method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

We can factorize

$$\begin{vmatrix}-k_1-k_2-\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 k_1 & -\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 -k_2 & 0 & -k_3-\lambda & -k_4 \\
 0 & 0 & k_3 & -k_4-\lambda\end{vmatrix}$$ $$=\begin{vmatrix}-k_1-k_2-\lambda & 0 \\
 k_1 & -\lambda \end{vmatrix}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
  -k_3-\lambda & -k_4 \\
  k_3 & -k_4-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=\ldots$$